# Is it possible to convert a character field in PostgreSQL to integer in JPA named query?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, seam

```
@Table(name = "Table")
class Table{
 String a
 Integer b
}
```

here column a in table t is character varying(32)

I have tried both of these and end-up with error.

```
SELECT t.b from Table t where Integer.parseInt(t.a) > 0 
Error : Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: schema "integer" does not exist
```

---

```
SELECT t.b from Table t where (t.a::integer) > 0 
Error : invalid token :: at line <line number>
```

Thanks

Comment: Your first solution is getting further, PostgreSQL is refusing it because it doesn't understand Integer.parseInt. I'm surprised your second solution is not working. Could you try `SELECT t.b FROM table t WHERE CAST(t.a AS integer) > 0`?

Answer (score 4):

The following query works fine for me.

```
SELECT t.b FROM table t WHERE CAST(t.a AS integer) > 0
```

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Lyons for this answer.